# Keras Concatenate layer dimensions acting up

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm creating a model using the functional API in tf.keras in which I'm doing a multi-input model.

The input for training is of shape (n_examples = 58667, n_dim = 2748). Each example is a concatenate of a 2048 and a 700 dimensions vector.

But I'm getting an error message that I don't understand:

*InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 0. Shapes are [1] and [0]. for 'model_27/concatenate_28/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [1,100], [0,100], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.*

Here are dummy inputs and imports to make it runnable:

```
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, losses, metrics, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Concatenate, Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

fake_train = np.random.rand(10000,2748)
fake_test = np.random.randint(0,1,(10000,1))

x_train, x_dev, y_train, y_dev = train_test_split(fake_train, fake_test, test_size = 0.2)
```

My model is created with this function:

```
def build_model():

   input0 = Input(shape=(2748,))

   branch1 = Lambda(lambda x:x[:2048])(input0)
   branch1 = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(branch1)
   branch1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(branch1)
   branch1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(branch1)


   branch2 = Lambda(lambda x:x[2048:])(input0)
   branch2 = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(branch2)
   branch2 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(branch2)
   branch2 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(branch2)


   out = layers.concatenate([branch1, branch2],axis=-1)
   out = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')(out)
   out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(out)

   model = Model(inputs=input0, outputs=out)    
   model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
                 loss='binary_crossentropy',
                 metrics=['accuracy', recall_m, precision_m])

   return model
```

Here are parameters for cross validation for the dummy data:

```
k = 3 #Number of folds for CV
num_epochs = 4 #for test only
batch_size = 1
```

And this is my cross-validation for the model, which started the error:

```
all_loss_histories = []
all_recall_histories = []
all_precision_histories = []
for i in range(k):
    val_data = x_train[i * num_val_samples:(i+1) * num_val_samples]
    val_targets = y_train[i * num_val_samples:(i+1) * num_val_samples]

    partial_train_data = np.concatenate(
        [x_train[:i*num_val_samples],
        x_train[(i+1)*num_val_samples:]],
        axis = 0)
    partial_train_targets = np.concatenate(
        [y_train[:i*num_val_samples],
        y_train[(i+1)*num_val_samples:]],
        axis = 0)

    model = build_model()

    history = model.fit(partial_train_data,
                    partial_train_targets,
                    epochs = num_epochs,
                    batch_size = batch_size,
                    verbose = 1,
                    validation_data = (val_data, val_targets),
                    use_multiprocessing=False)

    print('Finished training fold '+str(i+1))


    loss_history = history.history['val_loss']
    recall_history = history.history['val_recall_m']
    precision_history = history.history['val_precision_m']

    all_loss_histories.append(loss_history)
    all_recall_histories.append(recall_history)
    all_precision_histories.append(precision_history)
```

Any idea why there is an error?

Using python3.7 and tf 2.0 on a MacBook Pro 2018 (on OSX, not on a linux VM)

Thanks!

The complete error:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1609   try:
-> 1610     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1611   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 0. Shapes are [1] and [0]. for 'model_33/concatenate_34/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [1,100], [0,100], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    501       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    502       initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
--> 503       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
    504     finally:
    505       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    406     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    407         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 408             *args, **kwds))
    409 
    410     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1846     if self.input_signature:
   1847       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1848     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1849     return graph_function
   1850 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2148         graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2149         if graph_function is None:
-> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2039             arg_names=arg_names,
   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2042         self._function_attributes,
   2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    913                                           converted_func)
    914 
--> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    916 
    917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    356         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    360 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in distributed_function(input_iterator)
     71     strategy = distribution_strategy_context.get_strategy()
     72     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
---> 73         per_replica_function, args=(model, x, y, sample_weights))
     74     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
     75     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
    758       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
    759                                 convert_by_default=False)
--> 760       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    761 
    762   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   1785       kwargs = {}
   1786     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 1787       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   1788 
   1789   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2130         self._container_strategy(),
   2131         replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
-> 2132       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2133 
   2134   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
--> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    293 
    294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in train_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    262       y,
    263       sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 264       output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
    265 
    266   if reset_metrics:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in train_on_batch(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, output_loss_metrics)
    309           sample_weights=sample_weights,
    310           training=True,
--> 311           output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))
    312   if not isinstance(outs, list):
    313     outs = [outs]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _process_single_batch(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    250               output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics,
    251               sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 252               training=training))
    253       if total_loss is None:
    254         raise ValueError('The model cannot be run '

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _model_loss(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    125     inputs = nest.map_structure(ops.convert_to_tensor, inputs)
    126 
--> 127   outs = model(inputs, **kwargs)
    128   outs = nest.flatten(outs)
    129 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    845                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    846                 else:
--> 847                   outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    848 
    849             except errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError as e:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    706     return self._run_internal_graph(
    707         inputs, training=training, mask=mask,
--> 708         convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
    709 
    710   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask, convert_kwargs_to_constants)
    858 
    859           # Compute outputs.
--> 860           output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
    861 
    862           # Update tensor_dict.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    845                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    846                 else:
--> 847                   outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    848 
    849             except errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError as e:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py in call(self, inputs)
    180         return y
    181     else:
--> 182       return self._merge_function(inputs)
    183 
    184   @tf_utils.shape_type_conversion

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py in _merge_function(self, inputs)
    392 
    393   def _merge_function(self, inputs):
--> 394     return K.concatenate(inputs, axis=self.axis)
    395 
    396   @tf_utils.shape_type_conversion

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py in concatenate(tensors, axis)
   2706     return sparse_ops.sparse_concat(axis, tensors)
   2707   else:
-> 2708     return array_ops.concat([to_dense(x) for x in tensors], axis)
   2709 
   2710 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    178     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    179     try:
--> 180       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    181     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    182       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py in concat(values, axis, name)
   1429           dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape().assert_has_rank(0)
   1430       return identity(values[0], name=name)
-> 1431   return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
   1432 
   1433 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in concat_v2(values, axis, name)
   1255   _attr_N = len(values)
   1256   _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 1257         "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
   1258   _result = _op.outputs[:]
   1259   _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    791         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None, name=scope,
    792                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 793                          op_def=op_def)
    794       return output_structure, op_def.is_stateful, op
    795 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in create_op(***failed resolving arguments***)
    546     return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    547         op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def,
--> 548         compute_device)
    549 
    550   def capture(self, tensor, name=None):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
   3427           input_types=input_types,
   3428           original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3429           op_def=op_def)
   3430       self._create_op_helper(ret, compute_device=compute_device)
   3431     return ret

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   1771           op_def, inputs, node_def.attr)
   1772       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, grouped_inputs,
-> 1773                                 control_input_ops)
   1774     # pylint: enable=protected-access
   1775 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1611   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1612     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1613     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1614 
   1615   return c_op


ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 0. Shapes are [1] and [0]. for 'model_33/concatenate_34/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [1,100], [0,100], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.```
````

Comment: Can't you just use two inputs instead of using `Lambda` to slice your tensors?

Comment: I can do that and split the datasets outside of keras but isn't lambda doing the same? I'll try your way and I'll tell you if it works now

Comment: If you want to do this within a `Lambda` layer, you need to use `tf.gather`. I doubt it would be as simple as numpy indexing

Comment: There is no reason why you couldn't use slicing in a `Lambda` layer (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#__getitem__), I think the problem is not coming from here.
Can you reproduce this error with a random dataset? If so then please update your code, so that we can have an example we can copy-paste and run. 
Can you also post the entire error stack trace?

Comment: Could you also tell us what is `k`?

Comment: I edited the post with a random dataset and the imports and added the error stack. k is the number of folds for CV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want

```
Lambda(lambda x:x[:, :2048])(input0)
```

and

```
Lambda(lambda x:x[:,2048:])(input0)
```

since there is a batch axis which should be preserved. Your current code is splitting around 2048 **along the batch axis**, which results in one input to `concatenate` that has batch size 0, and one input that has batch size 1. Since the batch sizes don't match, they can't be concatenated.

Making this correction allows me to run your code without the error.