# tf.concat tensors with different length

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I have 2 tensors like:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
b = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

My desired output would be:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
 array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=int64)>
```

But when I try `tf.concat([a, b], axis=0)` I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [2,3] vs. shape[1] = [1,5] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras Concatenate layer dimensions acting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223142/keras-concatenate-layer-dimensions-acting-up)

Comment: @A.Najafi I think it doesn't. Lambda, if I'm not wrong, can't "expand" your tensor dimension adding 0 values, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
b = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

c = tf.concat([tf.pad(a, tf.constant([[0,0], [0,2]])), tf.expand_dims(b, axis=0)], axis=0)
tf.print(c)
```

```
[[1 2 3 0 0]
 [1 2 3 0 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5]]
```